# Upgrade /bin/bash on MacOS to v5+

Tags: bash, macos, kubeflow, google-anthos

I am trying to install Anthos Service Mesh (ASM) for a Kubeflow installation and need /bin/bash to be v5+. MacOS comes with Bash v3.2.57 which doesn't work. Simply installing Bash v5+ in "/usr/local/bin" doesn't work either as several shell scripts for the install points to "/bin/bash" and thus I still get the old version.

I had hoped I could just temporarily move the new bash v5+ to "/bin/bash" and then revert after completing the ASM install - something like this:

```
>>>$sudo mv /bin/bash /bin/bash_old
>>>$sudo cp /usr/local/bin/bash /bin
>>>$make install_asm
>>>$sudo mv /bin/bash_old /bin/bash
```

```
>>>mv: rename /bin/bash to /bin/bash_old: Operation not permitted
```

So that doesn't seem to be possible

What would be the best way to get around this? It doesn't seem to work just adding an alias to .zshrc in the hope that whenever I execute a shellscript with "#!/bin/bash" it would actually call "/usr/local/bin/bash":

```
~/.zshrc:
alias /bin/bash="/usr/local/bin/bash"

>>>$/bin/bash --version
>>>GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)

test_bash.sh:

#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash --version

>>>$sh ./test_bash.sh
>>>GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
```

Perhaps there is a way for me be permitted to move the binaries as in the example above?

By the way already the "/usr/local/bin/bash" is a link - not sure if that has any influence on what I am trying to do.

```
>>>$ll /usr/local/bin/bash
>>>/usr/local/bin/bash -> ../Cellar/bash/5.1.8/bin/bash
```

Any hints are warmly welcomed!

Comment: @KamilCuk That doesn't help if the shebangs say `/bin/bash`

Comment: A traditional approach would be to build a minimal `chroot` where you have full control over `/bin` inside it; but these are kind of cumbersome to set up, and I'm not sure how well it works on macOS (though it does seem to have `/usr/sbin/chroot` available).

Comment: Perhaps also look into Docker but I guess if you are using Kubernetes you are well aware of Docker already.

Comment: /bin is readonly in MacOS: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really?newreg=068dc403fea74a3eb1e434b955924023

Comment: You might have an easier time altering the install scripts in ASM: change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` so that the /usr/local/bin/bash can be earlier in your PATH than /bin/bash.

Answer (score -1):

I used a combination of adding my new shell location to the list of approved shells in `/etc/shells`, then changing my user's default shell with:

`chsh -s /path/to/new/bash/version`

as well as making sure my new bash location was exported to the front of my path not the end, so commands looking for just any bash find that first:

`export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/bash:$PATH`

No issues with this for far but this is a new machine and I'm just getting it set-up. If you have a `SHELL` environment variable set in any of your bash start-up scripts make sure to change it to your new bash binary also.